# Unable to show the glossary with \printglossary in latex

Tags: latex, overleaf

I was given a Latex project as template and I decided to add a glossary on it, however, `\printglossary` is not working. I can add and use different entries so I guess that the glossary creation is not the problem.

I am using Overleaf and if I try a completely new project with only the glossary (code bellow) `\printglossary` works fine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[acronym, toc]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\input{Bibliocosas/glossary.tex}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{First Section}

The \Gls{latex} typesetting markup language is specially suitable for documents that include \gls{maths}. \Glspl{formula} are rendered properly an easily once one gets used to the commands.


\clearpage

\section{Second Section}

\vspace{5mm}

Given a set of numbers, there are elementary methods to compute its \acrlong{gcd}, which is abbreviated \acrshort{gcd}. This process is similar to that used for the \acrfull{lcm}.


\clearpage

\printglossary

\clearpage

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\end{document}
```

I am using chapters intead of sections in the given project, is that the the cause of the problem?

Comment: Can you make a [mre] that does not rely on external files we don't have access to?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I had not noticed that in this example I was including the glossary entries in an external file: I was using the project provided as [example](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/glossaries#Show_the_glossary_in_the_table_of_contents) in Overleaf. At the end of the section you can see "Open an example of the glossaries package in Overleaf", that is the project I was using for testing.
Anyway, with `\printnoidxglossaries` seems to be working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `\makenoidxglossaries` and `\printnoidxglossaries` seems to apparently solve the problem.

I thought that I had already tried them but I guess I was wrong. However, I still don't know why the previous code does not work in the given project.

Comment: Glad I found this after 2 hours of testing, offline my glossary and acronyms lists compiled, but not in Overleaf. Your answer ensured they did compile in Overleaf! Also, `\printnoidxglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Acronyms]` and `\printnoidxglossary[title=Glossary]` allowed me to give a separate title to each list. (Instead of making the two lists with one command).

Comment: This formulation does not cut it with Tex Live 2022. Assuming you simply replaced the commands recommended by Overleaf by these you mention.

Answer (score 10):

As for me, I had the same issue but I fixed it by using glossaries-extra package after glossaries package using.

```
\usepackage[automake]{glossaries-extra}
```

Then clearing the cache.

Comment: Of the answers posted here as of 2024 Mar 1, this is the one that worked for me in a new self-hosted installation of Overleaf Community Edition.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue with Overleaf. The problem was that I uploaded the project as a zip and Overleaf created an additional nested directory in the root with the name of my project. Everything worked but not glossaries.

To solve this I just moved all files to the root directory by dragging each of it.